# jruby 9.3.4.0 NoMethodError: undefined method `new_ostruct_member' for No value for 'public' found

Tags: ruby, jruby, jrubyonrails, warbler

I updated to jruby from 9.3.2.0 to 9.3.4.0.

And now when I want to make the war file I get an error.

Any idea?

```
rvm use jruby-9.3.4.0
jruby -S bundle exec rake assets:clean
jruby -S bundle exec rake assets:precompile
jruby -S warble war

warble aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `new_ostruct_member' for No value for 'public' found
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/traits/war.rb:200:in `method_missing'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/traits/war.rb:53:in `default_webxml_config'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/traits/war.rb:27:in `before_configure'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/traits.rb:29:in `block in before_configure'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/traits.rb:29:in `each'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/traits.rb:29:in `before_configure'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/config.rb:215:in `initialize'
config/warble.rb:19:in `new'
config/warble.rb:19:in `initialize'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/task.rb:46:in `eval'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/task.rb:46:in `initialize'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/application.rb:27:in `new'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/application.rb:27:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/application.rb:79:in `run'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/application.rb:74:in `run'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/bin/warble:11:in `<main>'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/bin/warble:25:in `load'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.4.0/bin/warble:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Any luck?  I'm getting the same thing.

Comment: Possibly related to this, but I'm still having problems even with suggested fix:
https://github.com/jruby/warbler/issues/508

Comment: I opended an issue https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/7160 and pull request in warbler was created https://github.com/jruby/warbler/pull/513

Answer (score 1):

This was not going to be an answer, but I do not have enough reputation to just make a comment. And this has led to me finding a solution, so it is not all bad!

First the rant. April 2023, a year later, and I am getting this same issue. I am using JRuby 9.4.1, and Warbler version 2.0.5. I can see an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jruby/warbler/issues/508), that was opened January 2022, and is still open. Is Warbler now dead?

The issue seems to be that the `new_ostruct_member` method has been made private in JRuby, so one work-around is to bypass that protection.

Paste this code into warble.rb.

```
class Warbler::Traits::War::WebxmlOpenStruct
  def new_ostruct_member(name)
    send(:new_ostruct_member!, name)
  end
end
```

*Credit:* JesseChavez and kovyrin on Github

I also had to add warbler to my Gemfile, which was not necessary previously.

I had to do `bundle exec warble` to get it to run, but I did get a .war file at the end of it.

It turns out that (as of April/23) the Github version of Warbler is working, it is just awaiting the gem version, so another approach is to tell Bundler to go to Github.

```
gem 'warbler', '2.0.5', git: 'https://github.com/jruby/warbler', branch: 'master', platforms: :jruby
```

*Credit:* rcrews on Github

Again, I did `bundle exec warble` to get it to run, and again I did get a .war file at the end of it.

rcrews also say:

> Manually copy *.gemspec into the resulting war:
>
> mkdir WEB-INF && cp myapp.gemspec WEB-INF && zip myapp.war WEB-INF/myapp.gemspec && rm -r WEB-INF

I do not have a gemspec file in my project (should I?), and I have not tried to deploy the .war yet, so no comment on that bit.

Comment: I found even a better method last year. I kicked warble out. I now use jruby + puma and on front nginx+modsecurity

Answer (score 0):

After being annoyed with several pitfalls around warbler I found the time now to pack the needed function into an own Gem.
So here it is:

Jarbler: Pack a Ruby app into a self executing jar file including their Gem dependencies

```
> gem install jarbler
> cd app_dir
> jarble        # create the jar file with jRuby runtime
```

The application can then be started without having a jRuby environment by:

```
> java -jar AppName.jar
```

If you want to change the configuration (Defaults are for a Rails app), generate and adjust a config file by

```
> jarble config
```

See also: https://github.com/rammpeter/jarbler